# Can i use list as database in java

Tags: java

I want to search data which is added to list. Can I?
like select query in database.

this is my code

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (dataRow != null){
    list.clear();
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\t");
    for (String item:dataArray) { 
        list.add(item);
    } 
    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String txt = it.next();
        System.out.print(txt+"\t");
    } 
    System.out.println(); // Print the data line.
    dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); 
}
boolean a=list.contains(72);//////it is not working
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Make some effort to express your need clearly. Don't want to read your code to understand what you want to do

Comment: You seem to be looking for an integer inside a list of strings.

Comment: Why do you empty the list with list.clear() at the start of your while loop?

Comment: list is List of String you cannot search int 72 .

Comment: for not repetition i put list.clear() and 72 is one which is in string format in list

Answer (score 6):

The question starts with "Can I" so the answer is YES, you can. But you should NOT do it.

First, if you want a database to check if a value exists, use a database. If you still want to implement it in Java (which is temporary anyways if you don't store it somewhere after execution), I would highly recommend to use a HashMap. Complexity of retrieval from a HashMap is O(1) while ArrayList's complexity is O(n) for same operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason for the bug in the initial code is that you're searching for an Integer in a String array. Try this (note the quotes):

```
boolean a = list.contains("72");
```